# SQL 2012 Pivot - dynamic columns and result anomalies

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2012

I was asked to show some data as a pivot table to make it more readable, so after some research put this query together:

```
SELECT
    regionName,
    [Not Yet Set],
    [Not Applicable],
    [Not met],
    [Achieved],
    [Excelled],
    [Accepted],
    [Declined]
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        regionID,
        regionName,
        resultID,
        resultDesc
    FROM
        @tbl_results) ps
PIVOT
    (
        COUNT (resultID)
        FOR resultDesc IN
            (
            [Not Yet Set],
            [Not Applicable],
            [Not met],
            [Achieved],
            [Excelled],
            [Accepted],
            [Declined]
            )) as pvt
```

...which produces:

```
regionName      Not Yet Set Not Applicable Not met  Achieved  Excelled Accepted  Declined
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
China           3           2              1        0         0        0         0
United Kingdom  8           0              1        2         0        0         1
```

However from my understanding, the columns referenced in pvt have to exactly match the database row values in the underlying table.  This was a concern, so I re-wrote the query to use ID values instead

```
SELECT
    regionName,
    [1] as [Not yet set],
    [2] as [Not applicable],
    [3] as [Not met],
    [4] as [Achieved],
    [5] as [Excelled],
    [6] as [Accepted],
    [7] as [Declined]
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        regionID,
        regionName,
        resultID,
        resultDesc
    FROM
        @tbl_results) ps
PIVOT
    (
        COUNT (resultID)
        FOR resultID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])) as pvt
```

This produces this result set:

```
regionName      Not yet set  Not applicable    Not met    Achieved    Excelled    Accepted    Declined
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
United Kingdom  0            0                 0          2           0           0           0
United Kingdom  0            0                 0          0           0           0           1
United Kingdom  0            0                 1          0           0           0           0
United Kingdom  8            0                 0          0           0           0           0
China           0            2                 0          0           0           0           0
China           0            0                 1          0           0           0           0
China           3            0                 0          0           0           0           0
```

Can anyone explain to me why the regionNames get repeated in the above query now that resultID is being used to perform the COUNT?

Also, the resultDesc columns used in the pivot table are hard-coded (there are only these seven potential values in the result table).  Can these be pulled out dynamically so the procedure doesn't have to be updated whenever a new database row is created?  Or even better, only the descriptions contained within @tbl_results, for example pivot using `SELECT DISTINCT resultID, resultDesc FROM @tbl_results`

Comment: If you remove the `resultDesc` from your second query, does it resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your second query is that the `resultDesc` is being used in the `GROUP BY` for the `PIVOT` and you have distinct values, as a result you get separate rows for each `resultDesc`.

The second query should be:

```
SELECT
    regionName,
    [1] as [Not yet set],
    [2] as [Not applicable],
    [3] as [Not met],
    [4] as [Achieved],
    [5] as [Excelled],
    [6] as [Accepted],
    [7] as [Declined]
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        regionID,
        regionName,
        resultID
    FROM
        @tbl_results) ps
PIVOT
    (
        COUNT (resultID)
        FOR resultID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])) as pvt
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25a65/2).

If you want to use the `resultDesc`, then you can remove the `resultId` so the query is:

```
SELECT
    regionName,
    [Not yet set],
    [Not applicable],
    [Not met],
    [Achieved],
    [Excelled],
    [Accepted],
    [Declined]
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        regionID,
        regionName,
        resultDesc
    FROM
        tbl_results) ps
PIVOT
    (
        COUNT (resultDesc)
        FOR resultDesc IN ([Not yet set],[Not applicable],
                           [Not met],[Achieved],[Excelled],
                           [Accepted],[Declined])) as pvt
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25a65/3).

If you want to perform this dynamically, then you can use:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(resultDesc) 
                    from tbl_results
                    group by resultid, resultDesc
                    order by resultid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT regionname, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select regionid, regionname, resultdesc
                from tbl_results
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(resultdesc)
                for resultdesc in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25a65/6).

Edit #1, Based on your comment the error you are getting is because the temp table is out of scope for the dynamic SQL.  So you will need to create a user-defined type of a table, similar to:

```
create type mytable as table
(
  regionid int,
  regionname varchar(50),
  resultid int,
  resultdesc varchar(50)
);
```

Then you will pass the table into the dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(resultDesc) 
                    from @tbl_results
                    group by resultid, resultDesc
                    order by resultid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT regionname, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select regionid, regionname, resultdesc
                from @tbl_results
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(resultdesc)
                for resultdesc in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, N'@tbl_results mytable READONLY', @tbl_results
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e5064/4)

Comment: Wow thanks for such a detailed answer.  Okay removing the resultDesc from the query removes the duplicate rows.  For your answer on using dynamic SQL, although it compiles, when I run I get an error 'Must declare the table variable "@tbl_results".'  @tbl_results *is* declared though because its used earlier on.

Comment: @EvilDr the problem is that the temp table is create out of the scope of the dynamic sql so you will have to alter the code slightly.  See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, sorry buts its still throwing an error: 'Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type mytable.'

Comment: @EvilDr when I did this in SQL Server, I had to place a `GO` after creating the `type` if it is in the same script.

Comment: The code I posted was actually the last part of a very long stored procedure, so I don't think I can use GO or it will break the procedure up.  I assume its not possible to mix dynamic and standard SQL in the same script given your point about variable scope?  If I declare @tbl_results as MyType does that cause any permanent changes to the database?

Comment: @EvilDr When you create the `type` it is just like any other object in your database so it would be permanently available.  See [Create Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx) from MSDN

Comment: Okay thanks.  The confusion was because @tbl_results has always been a table variable for the scope of that procedure and nothing more.  I think I've enough to go on anyway, I think until MS hopefully one day allow columns to be created without dynamic SQL I'll just hard code the output.  Thanks very much for your answer.